# Webpack – circumvent dependency on folder structure inside 3rd party module

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

Using webpack, I use a require call to load a css file out of the `node_modules` folder.

Part of my config:

```
resolve: {
  modulesDirectories: ['src/js', 'node_modules'],
},
```

The actual require call looks like this: `require('purecss/build/pure.css')`.

While working flawlessly, I am a bit uneasy about the `purecss/build/` bit because I depend on the folder structure *inside* the third party module. If they change something, my app will inevitably break. Is there a way to circumvent this (e.g. globbing patterns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the [resolve.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias) config option. It lets you specify an alias for a location from which you'll load modules. Abstracting it this way means your source code can use whatever makes sense, and you can manage the dependency on the 3rd party path in your config.

Comment: Thank you, this indeed what I was looking for. Fun fact: I was already using aliases for JS files and didn't realise I could also use them for CSS files – webpack is new for me.